# Avoiding using Thread.sleep() when working with SqsListener

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-sqs

I have SQS listener, and under a certain condition, I need to wait 120 seconds before executing method1(). But as I know SQS listener works multithreaded. Is there a way to avoid using Thread.sleep() to reuse the thread rather than leave it waiting?
Here is listener code:

```
 @SqsListener(value = "${test}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
public void listenTransactionEvent(@Payload SQSEvent sqsEvent) {
    String sqsPlainMessage = sqsEvent.getMessage();
    if (sqsPlainMessage.equals("test")) {
        Thread.sleep(120 * 1000L);
        method1();
    } else {
        method2();
    }
}
```

and configuration:

```
@Bean
public QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMessageHandlerFactory(
        final ObjectMapper mapper,
        final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync
) {
    final QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueHandlerFactory = new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();
    queueHandlerFactory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync);
    queueHandlerFactory.setArgumentResolvers(Collections.singletonList(
            new PayloadMethodArgumentResolver(jackson2MessageConverter(mapper))
    ));
    return queueHandlerFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be looking for [java.util.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,long)) to schedule a [TimeTask](https://www.baeldung.com/java-timer-and-timertask) or even using a [java.util.concurrent.Future](https://www.baeldung.com/java-future) could release the thread calling listenTransactionEvent, but the waiting will just change place, sometimes depending on context Thread.sleep might be an acceptable solution.

Best regards.